# MFC ctrls and duplicate messages

Tags: c++, mfc

I have two CListCtrl objects in my form.  I want selected list in both of them be same.
How I can do it.
I want duplicate the message that sent to a ClistCtrl and send to other one.
How I can do it?
if this is a good way?
thanks herzl

Comment: Why do you want the selected "list" (or maybe you mean _item_?) to be the same? Are the lists' contents identical? What is the goal you wish to achieve? What is displayed by the two lists?

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Do you have two different lists, but with items such that each item in one list corresponds to some item in another list, and you want the program to automatically select the corresponding item in second list when user selects some item in first list?

Comment: @dialecticus yes I have two diffrent list. the problem is as your explanation.

Comment: @Alevy the list aren't identical. but the selected item in each list be same  as Dialecticus explain it for ex. if I have two list **A** and **B** I want when in  user select first Item from `A` in `B` fisrt Ietm selected Automaticly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, essentially what you're saying is that you want the lists to be **synchronized**.

You can easily achieve that by adding an event handler to catch the user's selection inside you list control, by adding: `ON_NOTIFY(LVN_ITEMCHANGED, IDC_LIST1, OnItemChangedList1)` to your dialog/window's message-map.
Inside `OnItemChangedList1()`, get the index of the currently selected item by calling `GetFirstSelectedItemPosition()`, and set that as the current index in your second list by calling `SetSelectionMark()`.

This way, whenever the user will click on the 2nd item, for example, in List_A, the 2nd item in List_B will be selected as well.

There ought to be a function that brings that row into view, if it's not in view already, but I can't find it.

I hope that raps it up, ListView's have changed a lot since I've used them, but feel free to ask more if anything is unclear.